# Read string with JSON inside function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I called to URL for getting data (the URL is not mine)
and the response is:

```
string data = w.DownloadString(url);
// response "MyCallBack([{\"symbol\":\"USDCHF\"},{\"symbol\":\"GBPUSD\"}])"
```

How can I get the value because the JSON inside function ("MyCallBack")
and when I trying to do parse is failed (the error is: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0, position 0.")

**Edit**

the URL look like xxx.xxx.com?callback=MyCallBack
when I remove the callback from URL  "xxx.xxx.com"
the answer still inside the bracket
**(** the JSON **)**

when I try do parse

```
var json1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(data);//or
var json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(data);
```

that failed and the error "Invalid JSON primitive: ."

**When I do**

```
    json = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2);
    var jsona = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json);
```

I remove the bracket first and last ([{value,value]}) I get [{value},{value}]
and that working (but I'm not sure it's the way to do it)

Comment: Maybe you can modify the `url` so that the server returns JSON instead of JSONP? This way you wouldn't need to trim the function away before deserializing. Are you by some chance passing this `MyCallBack` as a parameter to the url?

Comment: They give me only URL something like "http://xxxx.xxx.com/?callback=MyCallBack"

Comment: OK, now get rid of `?callback=MyCallBack` and send the request directly to `xxxx.xxx.com` as url.

Comment: When I remove the callback (xxxx.xxx.com)  I get
"([{\"symbol\":\"USDCHF\"},{\"symbol\":\"GBPUSD\"}])"
and not
"[{\"symbol\":\"USDCHF\"},{\"symbol\":\"GBPUSD\"}]"

Comment: Are you looking this in the Visual Studio Debugger? This is the string representation. Can you try deserializing the `data` variable you received with a JSON serializer? What happens if you put this url in your browser address bar for example? Normally you should get the proper JSON response. Otherwise I would be very surprised about how this server behaves.

Comment: The answer inside (JSON) and that not good (without callback xxx.xxx.com)
when I try do parse:
`var jsona = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(json);`
or
`var jsona = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json);`
that failed "Invalid JSON primitive: ."

**(** json **)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the page should return a valid JSON and they don't. For this reason, you have to remove all invalid characters from your respone.

A JSON string begins every time with a `[{` or `{"` so that you can figure out, at which index your JSON string starts and when it ends.

I have written very easy understandable method for doing that:

```
    private string FilterJsonResponse(string responseWithJson)
    {
        var indexFirstJsonArray = responseWithJson.IndexOf("[{", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        var indexFirstJsonElement = responseWithJson.IndexOf("{\"", StringComparison.Ordinal);

        string filteredJson;

        if (indexFirstJsonArray < indexFirstJsonElement && indexFirstJsonArray != -1)
        {
            filteredJson = responseWithJson.Remove(0, indexFirstJsonArray);

            var indexLastJsonArray = filteredJson.IndexOf("}]", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 2;
            filteredJson = filteredJson.Remove(indexLastJsonArray, filteredJson.Length - indexLastJsonArray);
        }
        else
        {
            filteredJson = responseWithJson.Remove(0, indexFirstJsonElement);

            var indexLastJsonElement = filteredJson.IndexOf("\"}", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 2;
            filteredJson = filteredJson.Remove(indexLastJsonElement, filteredJson.Length - indexLastJsonElement);
        }

        return filteredJson;
    }
```

Take care with this method, it works only, if the invalid characters doesn't contain a `"[{"` or `"{\""`!

Comment: Thanks, I use your code (I remove what I write json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2) )  
and use your code that works great and more flexible thanks :)